# Side-effect free version of Underscore.js default function?

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

To initialize an object using default values I am using Underscore's [default](http://underscorejs.org/#defaults) function. According to the documentation, it works like this:

```
var foo = _.defaults(object, *defaults)
```

It is described as:

> Fill in undefined properties in object with values from the defaults objects, and return the object. As soon as the property is filled, further defaults will have no effect.

Although it basically works fine, there is one thing I always stumble upon: The side effect of manipulating the original object.

If I run

```
var foo = { bar: 'baz' };
```

and then say

```
var bar = _.defaults(foo, { dummy: 23 });
```

not only, `bar` has a property called `dummy`, the original `foo` object has been changed as well. My current workaround is:

```
var bar = _.defaults({}, foo, { dummy: 23 });
```

Unfortunately, you can easily forget this. I think it's quite a strange behavior that the `defaults` function changes an input parameter as well as returning the result as return value. It should be either or.

How do you deal with that situation? Are there better ways to deal with this?

Comment: I completely agree with you. Generally changing arguments is an anti-pattern as it produces non-obvious side effects. I am surprised that this behavior is chosen by many frameworks like underscore and lodash. I believe it lures developers into writing buggy code.

Answer (score 4):

The function is doing exactly what it's documented to do. It's not uncommon to modify objects passed into functions, and it's not uncommon to return them. The return is a convenience thing, so that you can write code exactly like your "workaround."

Your "workaround" is the correct way to do it.

Another option would be to make `foo` the prototype of the new object:

```
var bar = _.defaults(Object.create(foo), { dummy: 23 });
```

...but I only know that works by looking at the [annotated source](http://underscorejs.org/docs/underscore.html#section-84) *(that link may rot, but it'll be near there)* of Underscore, since the documentation doesn't specify whether, when copying the defaults, it looks only for "own" properties. (It doesn't, it uses `in`.)

Also note that `Object.create` is ES5 and may require a shim on older browsers. The use above is shimmable (because I'm not using `Object.create`'s second argument).

---

I just re-read your title:

> Side-effect free version of Underscore.js default function?

If you don't like your workaround, a side-effect-free version is fairly easy to create:

```
function myDefaults() {
    var args = [{}];
    args.push.apply(args, arguments);
    return _.defaults.apply(_, args);
}
```

That creates a blank object and puts it at the beginning of the arguments, then chains to `_.defaults`.

Comment: No, that behavior perfectly meets the definition of "side-effect", see [the wikipedia definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Side_effect_(computer_science)): "In computer science, a function or expression is said to have a side effect if, in addition to returning a value, it also modifies some state or has an observable interaction with calling functions of the outside world."

Comment: @c089: Okay, fair enough on the terminology.

Comment: My downvote comes from the original terminology problem, happy to remove it.

Comment: @c089: We should clean up these comments.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that the documentation is correct.

In a constructor function you could skip using the return value at all. Something like:

```
function(options) {
    _.defaults(options, defaults);
   // you can now continue to use options instead of a new object
}
```

If that's not what you want your workaround is pretty good I think.

Answer (score 1):

I'd simply write a wrapper function for it:

```
function defs (template_obj, additions) {
    return _.defaults({},template_obj,additions);
}
```

Then simply use it like:

```
var bar = defs(foo, { dummy: 23 });
```

You can even add the function to underscore itself (via _.mixin I believe) if you prefer.